# How to build the war files for oAuth2-sample project?

Tags: java, maven, security, spring-security, authentication-flows

I cloned the project here https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample

Set appropriate version for parent in pom.xml of all 3 projects oauth2-client, oauth2-auth-server, resource-sercer to

```
    <version>1.6.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I added the 3 projects to modules section in auth-parent. I built war files using `mvn install.`

```
<modules>
    <module>auth-common</module>
    <module>common-crypto</module>
    <module>authentication-flows</module>
    <module>oauth2-auth-server</module>
    <module>oauth2-client</module>
    <module>oauth2-resource-server</module>
</modules>
```

I put the 3 generate war file in jetty/webapps. Client and Resource-server seem to load fine but oauth2-auth-server doesnt. At localhost:8080 I get `UNAVAILABLE` for oauth2-auth-server.

I tried debugging by adding `maven-jetty plugin` and `mvn jetty:run` for oauth2-auth-server. But I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'authenticationSuccessHandler' for bean class [com.ohadr.auth_flows.core.AuthenticationSuccessHandler] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.ohadr.oauth_srv.web.OhadAuthenticationSuccessHandler]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I see the problem - did you try build it from the main directory, by using maven command "mvn clean install"?

Maven will then build all sub-modules, which are **common-crypto** and **authentication-flows**.

My oAuth-Sample project is in use as an oAuth example as well as ["authentication-flows" logic](http://auth-flows-demo.appspot.com/).

Do you build this oAuth-sample for oAuth-sample, or for "authentication-flows"?

Hope that helps (and sorry about the delay)